# Proof with the union of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if $\,A\cap B=\emptyset\,$, then $\,A\cup B=\left(A\setminus B\right)\cup\left(B\setminus A\right)$.

I need to understand what proof technique to use to go about proving this statement as well as how to go about using it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Let x ∈ U.
x ∈ A ∪ B
⇔ x ∈ A or x ∈ B
⇔ (x ∈ A and (x ∈ B or x 6∈ B)) or (x ∈ B and (x ∈ A or x 6∈ A))
⇔ (x ∈ A and x ∈ B) or (x ∈ A and x 6∈ B)

Comment: What does the "6∈" mean?

Comment: How do you define set difference? If $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then $A-B = A\setminus B = A$.

Comment: Take an element of $A \cup B$. Assume it's not in $B-A$. What would happen if it didn't belong to $A-B$ either?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple proposition to proof. You're overcomplicating your attempts.

Assume $A \cap B = \emptyset$. What can you say about $B-A$?

Once you realize this, the proof becomes really easy.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}A\cup B
&=(A\cup B)\cap\Omega\\
&=(A\cup B)\cap\overline{(A\cap B)}\qquad\text{since }\Omega=\bar\varnothing\\
&=(A\cup B)\cap(\bar A\cup\bar B)\\
&=(\underbrace{A\cap \bar A}_\varnothing)\cup(A\cap \bar B)\cup(B\cap\bar A)\cup(\underbrace{B\cap\bar B}_\varnothing)\\
&=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\end{align}$